# how to set Hibernate second level cache lifespan to just one entity deploying on Wildfly (Infinispan)

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, wildfly, infinispan

Dears,

How can I set Hibernate second level cache lifespan (timeout) to just one entity deploying on Wildfly (Infinispan) ?

I have an entity that is shared by some nodes (that don't know each other), all tied in a central database.

I want to have a second level cache to avoid unnecessary database access. But I also want to expire this cache every 5 minutes to ensure that we have some kind of eventual consistency between nodes.

So I want to configure it via second level cache.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan is the default caching choice in Wildfly. Just enable the 2LC in persistence.xml (`hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true`) and annotate your cached entity with `javax.persistence.Cacheable`. You can setup expiration to 5 minutes through `hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.lifespan=300`, if you want the caches to be in sync you can cluster the nodes using `standalone-ha.xml`.

Comment: But how can I set just this entity to 5 minutes? But not set all others?

Comment: See documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-infinispan-config). It is possible to give individual entities expiration values. The most important thing apart from setting the entity FQN in the property is to not forget to put the deployment file name and persistence unit name.